# What is the size of ppvBits returned by CreateDIBSection?

Tags: winapi

I am trying to capture the screen.  I call `CreateDIBSection` using a `BITMAPINFO` initialized with the screen dimensions, number of planes = 1, bpp = 32, mode = rgb.  It then returns me a pointer to the bitmap data in `ppvBits`.  But how do I determine how many bytes are in this buffer?  It doesn't fill out the `biSizeImage` for me.  Should I be computing it from the bpp and dimensions?  Something like `width * height * (bpp/8)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for `BITMAPINFOHEADER` [explain how to calculate the "stride"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader) - that is the number of bytes from one row to the next.

> For uncompressed RGB formats, the minimum stride is always the image
> width in bytes, rounded up to the nearest DWORD. You can use the
> following formula to calculate the stride:
>
> stride = ((((biWidth * biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3)

To calculate the total number of bytes required for a bitmap you multiply the stride by the number of rows.

Note the requirement for bitmap rows to be DWORD-aligned - this is why the stride calculation is rounded up.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I was in a situation where I needed to convert a bitmap image off the clipboard to 24-bit colour. I figured since it's already in memory as BMP that GDI was suitable for the job. It's a bit antiquated, sure, but then this question was asked in 2020 so I guess I can't be the only one.

Anyway, I quickly ran up against this issue with CreateDIBSection. Sure, I could calculate the size myself using the stride, but I was a bit sketched out by that - especially when the documentation notes it is for *uncompressed* bitmaps specifically. Does CreateDIBSection calculate the buffer size the same way for compressed images, such as those using RLE? There doesn't seem to be any guarantee, or documentation on what it does in each scenario. Sure, compressed bitmaps are an edge case, but I'm taking an untrusted user input. How can I know the buffer is the right size?

After thinking about it for a while, I realized two alternative solutions to the problem.

### Method One: Using VirtualQuery

What is not entirely obvious from the [documentation for CreateDIBSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection) is that ppvBits is actually a Mapped View, like that returned by [MapViewOfFile,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) *even if you do not pass a File Mapping object!* Even if hSection is NULL, then CreateDIBSection creates its own File Mapping, and gives you the Mapped View to it. You can see this is true for yourself: it is possible to obtain the size with [VirtualQuery.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery)

To use VirtualQuery, we create a [MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-memory_basic_information) structure. We then pass it to VirtualQuery which populates this structure, and we then validate the result. If it worked correctly, the memory should be committed and the base address of the region (note: not the allocation base, which we don't care about - it is [unrelated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19466079/3591734) to what we're after) should be equal to ppvBits, the address of the Mapped View. When we're done, the size will be `memoryBasicInformation.RegionSize`.

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memoryBasicInformation = {};
const SIZE_T MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION_SIZE = sizeof(memoryBasicInformation);

if (VirtualQuery(ppvBits, &memoryBasicInformation, MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION_SIZE)
    != MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION_SIZE
    
    || memoryBasicInformation.State != MEM_COMMIT
    || !memoryBasicInformation.Protect
    || memoryBasicInformation.BaseAddress != ppvBits
    || !memoryBasicInformation.RegionSize) {
    return false;
}

DWORD bitmapSize = memoryBasicInformation.RegionSize;
```

### Method Two: Create A File Mapping

The VirtualQuery method works if all we're after is the size of the buffer, but what if we'd like to control the size? Let's say we want to blit a bitmap and afterward we'd like to do our own processing on it. The image is 24-bit, but working with 24-bit numbers is a bit tedious, and it'd be really nice if we could just use a DWORD and ignore the top byte. Unfortunately, because GDI creates a buffer of the exact right size, if we try and read the last pixel in the bitmap as a DWORD we'll be reading out of bounds and get an access violation.

To solve this, ideally we could add a padding byte on the end of the buffer. Well, we can do this by using a File Mapping. The name File Mapping here is [a bit misleading:](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130301-00/?p=5093) we're not actually going to need to create any file; the buffer will never leave memory. Rather, the File Mapping API lets us interact with a block of memory *as if* it were a file that had been mapped, so that's what we're going to do. The trick is to pass `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` to [CreateFileMapping,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) then pass the File Mapping to CreateDIBSection as hSection.

```
DWORD fileMappingSize = bitmapSize + 1;

HANDLE fileMapping = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, fileMappingSize, NULL);

if (!fileMapping || fileMapping == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    return false;
}

PVOID ppvBits = NULL;

HBITMAP bitmapHandle = CreateDIBSection(
    compatibleDCHandle,
    &bitmapInfo,
    DIB_RGB_COLORS,
    &ppvBits,
    fileMapping,
    0
);

if (!bitmapHandle) {
    return false;
}
```

In this example, I am assuming that `bitmapSize` is the size of your image and you want to add a single padding byte afterwards. GDI requires the `PAGE_READWRITE` permission be used when creating the File Mapping.

When we call CreateDIBSection with a File Mapping passed in, it opens a Mapped View and returns it as ppvBits. But the buffer pointed to by ppvBits will still be the exact right size for the bitmap, which we don't want. So, at this point you can blit your image with BitBlt or StretchBlt, perform whatever other operations you want, and flush it with GdiFlush. Once you've done that, we open our own Mapped View instead of using ppvBits, so that we can specify the full buffer size.

```
if (!DeleteObject(bitmapHandle)) {
    return false;
}

LPVOID mappedView = MapViewOfFile(fileMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, fileMappingSize);

if (!mappedView) {
    return false;
}
```

One thing to be careful of here is to ensure that the bitmap is deleted with [DeleteObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject) BEFORE we create our own Mapped View. Technically, forgetting to do so won't cause any error, but we will be needlessly occupying twice the amount of virtual memory that we actually need to. Calling DeleteObject on the bitmap will cause it to close its own Mapped View, invalidating ppvBits - which we want to happen in this scenario, because we don't care about ppvBits anymore and want to open our own Mapped View in its place.

It is also fine to use `FILE_MAP_READ` in the call to MapViewOfFile if we only intend to read the buffer - write permission is only required in the call to CreateFileMapping.

Note that, although the addresses of the ppvBits and mappedView variables will appear different, there is no memory copy occuring. Both are pointing to the same underlying memory, so this operation is quite fast. Read up on [File Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping) if you're interested in learning more.

This is just an example of what you could do with this technique. You could also use this to store multiple bitmaps in a single buffer back to back, leveraging the dwOffset argument of CreateDIBSection to access them. Note that the images must start at a DWORD-aligned offset for that to work.