# VirtualAlloc in specific memory range (Windows, x64)

Tags: c++, windows, virtualalloc

I am trying to allocate a memory region with a specified maximum absolute distance from a given base address.

For example, let's say the base address is `0x007FFFFFFF400000` and I want to allocate a block of memory with size `size` that is reachable through a relative jump with 32-bit displacement. That means the maximum allocation address would be `0x007FFFFFFF400000 + (1LL << 31) - size` (maybe a bit larger since the relative jump would count the displacement from after the jump instruction, but I safely underestimate).

I have written the following code to try accomplish this:

```cpp
void* allocate_around_2gb(const void* base_address, const size_t size) {
    const auto base = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(base_address);
    const auto num_pages_required = static_cast<size_t>(std::ceil((double)size / SystemInfo::page_size));

    // Align to allocation boundary for VirtualQuery
    const auto base_aligned = base - (base % SystemInfo::allocation_granularity);

    // Maximum allocation address
    const auto high_bound = base + (1ULL << 31) - size;

    // Start searching from the next 64 KB region, since VirtualAlloc
    // reserves 64 KB-aligned regions with MEM_RESERVE and non-NULL `lpAddress`
    auto curr = base_aligned + SystemInfo::allocation_granularity;

    bool found = false;

    // Search for higher addresses, left out the backwards search for clarity
    while (curr < high_bound) {
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
        std::memset(&mbi, 0, sizeof(mbi));

        if (VirtualQuery(reinterpret_cast<void*>(curr), &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) {
            // If we find a MEM_FREE region with enough space, use it
            if ((mbi.State & MEM_FREE) && mbi.RegionSize >= (num_pages_required * SystemInfo::page_size)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // `curr` is always aligned to the allocation granularity (64 KB)
        curr += SystemInfo::allocation_granularity;
    }

    if (!found) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return VirtualAlloc(reinterpret_cast<void*>(curr), size,
        MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
}
```

However, I am always getting `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` as the `VirtualAlloc` error code. Any ideas why this could be, even though the region is `MEM_FREE` and has the right size?

Comment: base address is too high, current Intel/AMD processors are limited to a 48-bit virtual address, half of which is available to userland.  0 to 7FFF'FFFFFFFF. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces.  Note that the base_aligned calculation is not correct, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465213/what-is-difference-between-baseaddress-and-allocationbase-in-memory-basic-inform/19466079#19466079

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does indeed work with lower addresses. Are you implying `base_aligned` should be page (4K) aligned instead of allocation granularity (64KB) aligned?

Comment: You need to call VirtualQuery() and use MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.AllocationBase to ensure you can increment by the granularity.